# Proof-verification: $R$ is transitive iff $R \circ R ⊆ R$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, relations, function-and-relation-composition

This is Velleman's exercise 4.3.8 (**And not a duplicate of** "[$R$ is transitive if and only if $ R \circ R \subseteq R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711529/r-is-transitive-if-and-only-if-r-circ-r-subseteq-r)"):

Here's my proof of it:

Proof.

($\rightarrow$) Suppose $R$ in transitive. Let $(x, z)$ be an arbitrary element of $R \circ R$. By the definition of composition there must be some $y$ such that $(x, y) ∈ R$ and $(y, z) ∈ R$. Since $R$ was transitive then from $(x, y) ∈ R$ and $(y, z) ∈ R$, we get $(x, z) ∈ R$. Since $(x, z)$ was arbitrary then we can conclude that $R \circ R ⊆ R$.

($\leftarrow$) Suppose $R \circ R ⊆ R$. Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be arbitrary elements of the set $A$ such that $(x, y) ∈ R$ and $(y, z) ∈ R$. Now by the definition of composition we have $(x, z) ∈ R \circ R$. Hence from our hypothesis we get $(x, z) ∈ R$. Since $x$, $y$, and $z$ were arbitrary then $∀x ∈ A∀y ∈ A∀z ∈ A((x Ry ∧ yRz) → x Rz)$. Ergo $R$ is transitive.

From ($\rightarrow$) and ($\leftarrow$), $R$ is transitive if and only if $R \circ R ⊆ R$.

Is my proof correct? I'm particularly concerned with the part that I introduced the set "A" in the backward direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks good to me. Introducing the base set $A$ is not really problematic, although you could say "arbitrary elements from $A$, the base set of $R$", or something, to make it crystal clear what set $A$ is.

Comment: maybe, since you want a confirmation of your **proof**, you could use that also in the title of your question instead of the word **prove**, which at least to me sounds like you want others to prove it.

Comment: Could you please suggest a title of that purpose? Wouldn't be tedious? Plus I tagged "proof-verification" and not "proof-writing", isn't that sufficient for anyone to understand your point?

Comment: I mentioned it on meta: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26961/prove-that-vs-confirmation-of-proof-in-the-title, and decided to change it. Thank you.

Comment: Correct, complete and well written.

Comment: What does $R\circ R$ mean?

Comment: @Jack: When $R$ and $S$ are relations on a set $X$, their composite $S \circ R$ is a relation on $X$ defined for all $x,z \in X$ by declaring $$(x,z) \in S \circ R \text{ if and only if } x\, R\, y \text{ and } y \, S\, z \text{ for some } y \in X$$